# Post request with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a post request with node.js and when I try to run it, I get the data to show up in the console but noot the body of my HTML.  In the console I get the error

```
app.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/addAnimal net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
postData @ app.js:4
(anonymous) @ app.js:25
app.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

It seems like the function is working but not the actual post request part.  I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

server.js:

```
projectData = {};

/* Express to run server and routes */
const express = require('express');

/* Start up an instance of app */
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/* Middleware*/
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

/* Initialize the main project folder*/
app.use(express.static('project1'));

const port = 8000;
/* Spin up the server*/
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
 function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
  };

// GET route
app.get('/all', sendData);

function sendData (request, response) {
  response.send(projectData);
};

// POST route
app.post('/add', callBack);

function callBack(req,res){
  res.send('POST received');
}

// POST an animal
const data = [];


  // TODO-Call Function



app.route('/addAnimal')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    data.push(req.body)
  })
```

app.js

```
/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json()
        // console.log(newData);
        return newData.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error)
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };

  // TODO-Call Function

  postData('/addAnimal', {animal:'lion'});
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only **one reason** why you got message like it, it's because you never send `response` to the client.

‍ So, **You should to send response** to the client. For an example, you can look at this code below:

```js
app.route('/addAnimal')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    data.push(req.body);
    // send data to client
    // you can change req.body with the object what you want to sent do the client
    res.status(200).send(req.body);
  })
```

**Update:** Addtional information

> Make sure you call the endpoint: `http://localhost:8000/addAnimal`.

**Frontend:** Make sure your code like this code below

```js
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });
    try {
      console.log(await response.json());
      return await response.json()
    }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    };
};
```

I hope it can help you .

Comment: I was thinking the same but wasnt sure since OP is also seeing ```app.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch```

Comment: I'm still not seeing the result in the body of the HTML.  Any idea why?

Comment: Have you check your console.log in your browser when you post your data?? what's there?

Answer (score 0):

Change the app.js code with the below.

```
/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });

  try {
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
  }
};

// TODO-Call Function
(async function(){
  let res = await postData("/addAnimal", { animal: "lion" });
  console.log(res);
})();
```

And also change the post method like below.

```
app.route('/addAnimal')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    data.push(req.body);
    res.status(200).send(data);
  })
```

Comment: I'm still not seeing the result in the body of the HTML.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.route('/addAnimal')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    data.push(req.body);
    res.send('done'); // send response
  });
```

Comment: You may want to check out [how to structure an Express application](https://codesearchable.com/de/463081/)